# Creating A Line Chart With Chart.js And PHP\MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, chart.js

I'm attempting to create a line chart utilizing Chart.js, pulling the data from MySQL using PHP.

I have the following code so far, but I'm not entirely certain if I'm structuring the data correctly for ChartJS.

```
$stmtz = $pdo->prepare('SELECT seen FROM vast.subscribers WHERE email LIKE \'%@%\' AND owner = ? AND seen between (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) and CURDATE()');
$stmtz->execute( [ $account['id'] ]);
$emails_seen = $stmtz->fetchAll();

$stmtz = $pdo->prepare('SELECT seen FROM vast.subscribers WHERE website LIKE \'%.%\' AND owner = ? AND seen between (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) and CURDATE()');
$stmtz->execute( [ $account['id'] ]);
$sites_seen = $stmtz->fetchAll();


$data = array();
foreach($emails_seen as $s) {
array_push($data,$data['email'] = $s['seen']);
};
foreach($sites_seen as $s) {
array_push($data,$data['site'] = $s['seen']);
};

print json_encode($data);
type here
```

I tried utilizing this PHP MySQL code with no result.

Comment: Your code sample contains nothing related to `chart.js`; to debug a chart.js project that's included in a php page, we'll typically ask the OP to show us the source from browser, *after php has run*, because we can't really debug the php part not having access to the database. So please start really coding the chart itself and when you'll get stuck, update your question or ask a new one, we'll  be happy to help